# Property 'positive_rule' does not exist on type '{ addMore(): void; remove(index: any): void;

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component

```
data() {
    return {
      positive_rule: [
        {
          positive_rule: "",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
methods: {
    addMore() {
      this.positive_rule.push({
        positive_rule: "",
      });
    },
   remove(index: any) {
      this.positive_rule.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
```

> can someone please help me by correcting this code snippet so that the 'addMore' function works cheers!

Comment: can you extend your component definition? I don't see any error on the snippet you provided

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to write it this way:

```
methods: {
addMore: () => {
  this.positive_rule.push({
    positive_rule: "",
  });
},
remove: (index: any) => {
  this.positive_rule.splice(index, 1);
},
}
```